# angular radio button set checked

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have multiple radio button groups
i need to set one of each group (maybe none) as selected

datasource

[image]

html Code

```
<div class='row' ng-show="mk.selectedTypeAttributesID.length != 0">
                                            <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6' ng-repeat="att in selectedTypeAttributesID">
                                                <div class="switch-field">
                                                    <div class="switch-title">{{att.name}}</div>
                                                    <div>
                                                        <input ng-repeat-start="val in att.Values" class="bttn-input" type="radio" id="switch_{{val.val}}" name="switch_{{att.id}}"  value="{{val.val}}" ng-click="mk.AttChange(att.id,val.val)"  />
                                                        <label ng-repeat-end class="bttn-input" for="switch_{{val.val}}">{{val.val}}</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

i need to use the value of 'Selected' On the datasource to set the checkbox 
source Update

[image]

Comment: Use ng-model, as documented: https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/docs/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

Comment: ng-model="val.Selected" not working

Comment: Yes, of course. That's not how it works. Read the documentation carefully. The ng-model must contain the **value** of the selected radio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ng-model` to select the radio button..

Where `ng-model` holds the selected value as shown below.

```
$scope.options = [{Selected: false, val: "red"}, {Selected: true, val:"Black"}, {Selected: false, val:"Pink"}];

$scope.selected = undefined;

var findResult = $scope.options.find(function(x){ return x.Selected == true });

if(findResult){
    $scope.selected = findResult.val;
}
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vbqy39n1/9/)

---

Edit: Since the sources of the checkboxes are dynamic then build a dynamic selection tree for modal to bind to..

Here's an example:

```
$scope.options = [{ 0 : [{Selected: false, val: "red"}, {Selected: true, val:"Black"}, {Selected: false, val:"Pink"}]}, { 1 : [{ Selected: false, val: "2" }, { Selected: true, val: "1" }]}];

$scope.choices = [];

for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys($scope.options).length; i++){
    var keys = Object.keys($scope.options);
    $scope.choices.push({ Id: keys[i], Value: $scope.options[i][keys[i]].find(function(x){ return x.Selected == true }).val });
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vbqy39n1/25/)

Comment: Wow, that's a serious abuse of filter(). Filter is supposed to filter, not to do something for each element. That's what forEach is for. An even better option would be to use find(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: You're right.. let me modify it, I done it at speed while waiting for project to publish :)

Comment: that's close but i have dynamic datasource  i have uploaded new image i have multiple radio groups and dynamic etc one for size,one for model please note the html code

Comment: Well, I showed you how to do it, I'm not going to write code for you. You need to modify this to suit your problem. You can't just set the selected value inline because you need to reference it somehow using ng-model and ng-model can not contain inline logic. I see no problem using this method and update stuff accordingly, try using `$scope.$watch` if you need to listen to change events or use the existing click event you have to update further values down the line (or up the line)...

Comment: i mean i can't declare a variable $scope.selected = undefined; because i don't know how many radio

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a solution like so?

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.selectedTypeAttributesID = [{
      id: 1,
      Values: [{
        val: "red",
        selected: ""
      }, {
        val: "green",
        selected: ""
      }, {
        val: "blue",
        selected: ""
      }]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      Values: [{
        val: "1",
        selected: ""
      }, {
        val: "2",
        selected: ""
      }, {
        val: "3",
        selected: ""
      }]
    }
  ];
  $scope.setVal = function(att, index, val) {
    for (var k of att.Values) {
      k.selected = "";
    }
    att.Values[index].selected = val;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6' ng-repeat="att in selectedTypeAttributesID">
      <div class="switch-field">
        <div class="switch-title">{{att.name}}</div>
        <div>
          <input ng-repeat-start="val in att.Values" class="bttn-input" type="radio" id="switch_{{val.val}}" name="switch_{{att.id}}" ng-value="val.val" ng-click="setVal(att, $index, val.val)" />
          <label ng-repeat-end class="bttn-input" for="switch_{{val.val}}">{{val.val}}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <pre>{{selectedTypeAttributesID | json}}</pre>
</div>
```